# How to make website live? (From the point of having it as a Spring MVC project in Netbeans)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netbeans, web, hosting

Silly question as I just started web dev. Consider that I've got the project build on Spring MVC Framework in the Netbeans (a web site). I would like to make it live.

1. What is the actual process of making it live considering the fact that I bought the domain and got the hosting? i.e. you upload project in the repository of hosting provider? (not sure if the question is correct, hence correct me if it's wrong)
2. Can I somehow connect the repository of hosting provider with my Netbeans to update my web site directly from it? (like it works f.e. with svn repository)

Comment: Probably best to ask your hosting provider how to do that. It varies from host to host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's a java application that you want to host / publish, so you will need [java hosting](http://gojava.net) company.

1. You need domainname, you can buy one, or get free domainname (there's a few options, you can get free .tk domain, some hosts offer free domain with 1 year prepay as well).
2. Yes you can connect to your host's SVN with your Netbeans IDE. But deployment process depends on how you will set up your environment on host side. SVN is a place where you keep your source code, not a compiled java application. You can use your host's SVN server, but then still you need to compile java code and build war file which you can deploy under your java server. Some java hosting companies offer Apache Maven, which can helps in your case. Another solution is to build war locally, and upload ready app to your java host account (try to use SFTP or SCP, most of java hosting companies offer SSH access to your account, try to avoid FTP as it's pretty unsecure).